# Integration with Bessel function as result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

When I try to calculate this integral,

```
1/(2*Pi)*Integrate[ Exp[I*2*θ]*Cos[1/2 (7 + Cos[θ])], {θ, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

Mathematica is unable to compute it. But the result is known to be `-BesselJ[2, 1/2] Cos[7/2]`, using the integral form of the Bessel functions. Why doesn't Mathematica calculate this integral analytically? There is no issue in computing it using `NIntegrate`.

Comment: Because ,nothing is perfect.A perfect CAS does not exist and never will be.

Comment: Mathematica can't take `Integrate[Exp[-Cosh[x]], {x, 0, Infinity}]` either...

Answer (score 3):

```
1/(2*Pi)*Integrate[#, {θ, 0, 2*Pi}] & /@
 TrigExpand[Exp[I*2*θ]*Cos[1/2 (7 + Cos[θ])]]

(* -BesselJ[2, 1/2] Cos[7/2] *)
```

Comment: I've used Map with pure functions in other applications, but can you please explain what that code does?

Comment: @theorist `TrigExpand` generates a sum of expressions. `/@` maps `Integrate` over all terms, thereby integrating the terms of the sum separately. The `Plus` head of the sum is not affected by this, so the results of the individual integrations will be summed up to the final result.

Answer (score 2):

With little help MMA can do it.

Using a trick: `Cos[x] == Exp[I x] // Re // ComplexExpand`

```
Integrate[1/(2*Pi)*Exp[I*2*θ]*Exp[I*1/2*(7 + Cos[θ])], {θ, 0, 2*Pi}] // Re // ComplexExpand

(*-BesselJ[2, 1/2] Cos[7/2] *)
```